# TinyMCE - exclude elements

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm wondering if it's possible to exclude some elements from TinyMCE's editable DIV. Here's an example code:

```
<div class="editable-area">
    <h2>heading</h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <div class="exclude-this-element"></div>
</div>

.exclude-this-element:empty:before { content: "Editable Area"; }

tinymce.init({
    inline: true,
    fixed_toolbar_container: '.toolbar'
});
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, '.editable-area');
```

The problem is that, when TinyMCE is initialized on `.editable-area`, it adds `<br>` tag to `.exclude-this-element` and `Editable Area` text stops appearing. Actually, I think that entire `.exclude-this-element` is erased after a while. Can this element be excluded completely from being altered by TinyMCE?

I would also like to attach some actions (like `click` or jQuery UI functions) to `.exclude-this-element` and make it not interfere with TinyMCE.

I tried `valid_children`, `valid_elements` and `invalid_elements` but I think that none of these can be used to exclude any elements from being editable (it only excludes them when saving the content of the editor): http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can use **content editable** method

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:property.tinymce.Env.contentEditable and also

**noneditable** plugin. This plugin makes elements with **noneditable** class to be - non editable

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:noneditable

**EDIT:**

Try to block the BR elements by adding this in tinyMCE INIT configuration:

```
 force_br_newlines : false,
 forced_root_block : "", 
 convert_newlines_to_brs: false,
```

If the BR tags appear inside content when you paste it from somewhere you also can add this:

```
paste_preprocess: function(pl, o) {
o.content = o.content.replace(/<br><\/br>/gi, " ");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This plugin added `data-mce-contenteditable="false"` to my element but still TinyMCE inserts unwanted `<br>` inside that element and my `:empty` selector doesn't work.

Comment: Okay! See the Edit of my answer!

Comment: I did all that and the element still reacts to "delete" key on my keyboard (but I can't write in it so that's one less problem) and it still inserts unwanted `<br>` inside. Too bad that that's not possible or not easily doable because I'd like to use TinyMCE with jQuery UI Resizable but TinyMCE deletes my resizable handle (which has to be inside the editable DIV because jQuery UI forces that).